# Oracle label security in Oracle 12c not configured

Tags: oracle, security

I installed Oracle 12c release1 (12102) Enterprise Edition on win x64 server 2012 and created a database using DBCA with OLS component selected (account LBACSYS also unlocked).

After finished, I tried to use OLS but it said that this feature is not configured. Running chopt enable lbca but this option is not available.

---

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> chopt enable lbac

Incorrect option name: lbac

usage:

chopt <enable|disable> <option>

options:
                  dm = Oracle Data Mining RDBMS Files
             ode_net = Oracle Database Extensions for .NET
                olap = Oracle OLAP
        partitioning = Oracle Partitioning
                 rat = Oracle Real Application Testing

e.g. chopt enable rat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [Label Security Administrator's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OLSAG/config.htm#OLSAG3794) and [Database Vault Administrator's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DVADM/dvdisabl.htm#DVADM012):

Check if OLS is enabled from sqlplus:

```
SELECT VALUE FROM V$OPTION WHERE PARAMETER = 'Oracle Label Security';
```

Check if OLS is configured:

```
select name, status, description from dba_ols_status;


NAME     STATUS  DESCRIPTION
 -------------------- ------ ------------------------ -------------
 OLS_CONFIGURE_STATUS FALSE  Determines if OLS is configured
 OLS_DIRECTORY_STATUS FALSE  Determines if OID is enabled with OLS
 OLS_ENABLE_STATUS  FALSE  Determines if OLS is enabled
```

Log into the database instance as user SYS or a user who has been granted the LBAC_DBA role.

If OLS is not yet configured, run the following procedure to configure OLS:

```
SQL> EXEC LBACSYS.CONFIGURE_OLS;
```

Run the following procedure to enable OLS:

```
SQL> EXEC LBACSYS.OLS_ENFORCEMENT.ENABLE_OLS;
```

Restart the database.

```
CONNECT SYS AS SYSOPER
Enter password: password

SQL> SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
SQL> STARTUP;
```

For Oracle Real Application Cluster (Oracle RAC) environment or a multitenant environment, repeat these steps for each Oracle RAC node or PDB on which you disabled Oracle Label Security.

Comment: SQL> SELECT VALUE FROM V$OPTION WHERE PARAMETER = 'Oracle Label Security';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FALSE

SQL> EXEC LBACSYS.OLS_ENFORCEMENT.ENABLE_OLS;
BEGIN LBACSYS.OLS_ENFORCEMENT.ENABLE_OLS; END;

*
第 1 行出现错误:
ORA-12459: 未配置 Oracle Label Security
ORA-06512: 在 "LBACSYS.OLS_ENFORCEMENT", line 3
ORA-06512: 在 "LBACSYS.OLS_ENFORCEMENT", line 25
ORA-06512: 在 line 1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. OLS is not registered or enabled yet. The error message said that OLS need be configured first. But don't know how to configure this. Already add OLS component through DBCA.

Comment: Added also in my answer now. If not yet configured, you have to run procedure EXEC LBACSYS.CONFIGURE_OLS; before enabling OLS.